# using variable in jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

i imported my script

```
<script src="/test.js"></script>
```

and the content is

```
var test= $(document).find('aside#bar');
var list= test.find('ul');
```

then i using following script to append string

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(list).text("testing message");
});
</script>
```

but chrome console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined`

how can i use variable in jquery?

**Update**

i discovered all script is not work in that page

i use

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/test.js"></script>
    <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).html("testing message");
});
    </script>
```

but nothing append,chrome console doesn't log anything

Comment: what happened when you put all your code in one JS file/

Comment: Are you sure you linked to the external JS file **before** the inline `<script>` tag?

Comment: yes,order is jquery.js,test.js,inline-js

Comment: If you embedded those scripts in the `head` element or somewhere in `body` before the elements you are trying to select in your first external script are actually existing in the document, then your variables `test` and `list` will simple not reference any elements when you try to work with them in your later code that gets triggered `onready`.

Answer (score 2):

In your test.js file you declare a local variable. You have to declare it global using `window.variableName` like bellow:

```
window.test= $(document).find('aside#bar');
window.list= test.find('ul');
```

Then you will be able to access it from other Javascript files that were loaded **after** test.js.

Comment: If that's the whole content of the script (`test.js`), then the variables are global.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if /test.js is being loaded in Chrome. I think the URL you are giving to this file might be wrong

   ```
   <script src="/test.js">
   ```

   Open [Chrome's Network panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network), and reload the page. Are you seeing a Red error message when the `test.js` script is trying to load?

   If this page is, say, `http://localhost/test/mypage.html`, then `src='/test.js'` will load `http://localhost/test.js`. Because of the `/` in the beginning. So check the URL path and see if the script is getting loaded first.
2. `test.js` script is just saying `var test = ..., var list = ...`. But at this point, the document may not even have loaded! But of course, if your script `test.js` got loaded properly - then it would have shown an error for the `test` and `list` variables itself. Since you're not seeing errors when this variables are getting set, my first guess is that `test.js` is *not* getting loaded. Fix the script loading first, and then fix the script itself:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var test = ...
       var list = ...
   });
   ```
3. But again, **this will also not work** when you try to use `test` or `list` somewhere else! Because they are declared using `var`. `var` creates only local variables, so they won't be available outside the function (if you check above, we're wrapping the `var test =..., var list = ...` inside a `function() { }`, so they won't be available outside that function). So make them like:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       window.test = ...
       window.list = ...
   });
   ```

   You can also accomplish the same just by removing the `var` keyword, but that has its own problems. Make sure you read [Javascript Variable Scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) for a start.
4. Use either type or language for all script tags:

   ```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(...)
   </script>
   ```

Comment: You don't need `type` or `language` in HTML 5 but the rest is spot on. +1

Answer (score 0):

just use `list.html("test message")` or `list.text("test message")`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  list.html("testing message");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hVsDg/)**

**EDIT:**

and because of use jquery function in `test.js`

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>  <= First
<script src="test.js"></script> <= Second
```

Comment: can  i put those variable to external js?

Comment: i already put jquery at first,but nothing works , i don't know why

Comment: @jkjk : is your path `/test.js` is correct? see this in view source!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't define variables when the document is ready??

You can try in the script

```
$(
   var test= $(document).find('aside#bar');
   var list= test.find('ul');
);
```

and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(list).text("testing message");
});
</script>
```

But I would do

```
$(
       var test= $(document).find('aside#bar');
       var list= test.find('ul');
       $(list).text("testing message");
    );
```

Finaly.... what is aside#bar ????

aside is a class?? You forget the dot?? .aside?? The problem maybe there.

Sorry for my bad english and hope this help! Bye!

Comment: $(
   var test= $(document).find('aside#bar');
   var list= test.find('ul');
);

Comment: The `$( var ... )` part is invalid JavaScript. I assume you wanted to pass a function to `$`.